# Аналоги Netty для c++

Tags: java, c++, асинхронность

Некоторое время использовал фреймворк Netty для создания асинхронного неблокирующего сервера. Сейчас подумываю перекатываться на c++, есть ли аналоги Netty для c++? Желательно не медленнее Netty.

Comment: Ну, если есть аналог для С++, наверняка будет быстрее

Comment: Быстрее будет на `С` без STL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть библиотеки [libevent](https://libevent.org/) и [libuv](http://libuv.org/).